# excel 2003 VBA: macro not found

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting an error when calling a function via the OnTime method
I tried what's written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211715/how-to-make-a-macro-which-executes-periodically-in-excel) (and even posted a comment in the end) and I keep getting an error:

> The macro 'I:\myFolder\test.xls'!MacroName was not found

When calling the function `MacroName` from anywhere in the script, it works fine.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your problem is that the code is not in a standard module, and instead in the ThisWorkbook module...I'm not sure why but the code needs to be in a standard module to work, though you may want to try changing the OnTime method call to "ThisWorkbook.Subname"

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your "**macro level security**" as suggested by [this Microsoft technote](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262876) ?

> On the Tools menu, point to Macro, and then click Security.
> On the Security Level tab, change your setting to either Medium or Low.
>
> NOTE: The setting that you will want varies according to your circumstances. The default in Excel is Medium.

---

Now, when it comes to [the code of MacroName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211715), **you can only put the event procedure in the ThisWorkbook module** (i.e Macro_Name).

The other procedures must go in a normal module.

Answer (score 0):

Does the path shown in the error message match the location of the workbook that contains the macro?

It could be something else, but any time a path is displayed I get suspicious that I've loaded something from a different location and Excel is still (correctly, since it doesn't know you moved the file) looking for the macro in the original location.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the path matches. this is my first ever macro, so i recodnize it :)
Oddly enough, now it works, but only when MacroName is placed in a new Module.

How can that be explained?

Comment: I just completed my answer: only the event procedure should be kept in 'ThisWorkbook'