# Do Action if user returns to Excel from another Application

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook that has links to a webpage. The user can click on the links, which minimize the Excel window and open their browser. When they are done with the site, they minimize or close their browser, which returns them to Excel (as it was their previous active window).

I would like VBA to take an action (update a table) when the user is returned to Excel.

I've looked at the Workbook_WindowActivate event, but this only works if you are moving from one Excel Workbook to another within the Excel Application.

Maybe I could use Application.name or the Windows function GetActiveWindow somehow but I am not sure how best to do this.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: does the user need to close the IE window or just minimize?

Comment: I believe the user can either close or minimize the browser window.

Comment: Few more questions, Are the links Excel Links or is the launching of the browser done after an onclick event and is handled by your VBA code?

Comment: They are Excel links. VBA is not involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've ended up doing. I borrowed quite a bit from this post: [How to make a macro which executes periodically in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211715/how-to-make-a-macro-which-executes-periodically-in-excel/211779#211779)

When the user clicks on a hyperlink, the code starts periodically checking whether Excel is their active window. I've found that the GetActiveWindow function returns zero if the user is not in the Excel application and some positive number if they are. If the code finds that the user returned to Excel from a different window (the previous check found that they were in a different window and the current one finds they are in Excel) then my table gets updated and the timer stops checking for the active window.

Doing it this way has the advantage of working for any web browser.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ExcelIsActive As Boolean
Private Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Dim m_dtNextTime As Date
Dim m_dtInterval As Date
Dim DisableFlag As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Call start
End Sub

Public Sub Enable(Interval As Date)
    Call Disable
    m_dtInterval = Interval
    Call starttimer
End Sub

Private Sub starttimer()
    m_dtNextTime = Now + m_dtInterval
    Application.OnTime m_dtNextTime, "TestActive"
End Sub

Public Sub TestActive()
    If GetActiveWindow > 0 Then
        If ExcelIsActive = False Then
            ExcelIsActive = True
            Call RefreshQuery
        End If
    Else
        ExcelIsActive = False
    End If
    If Not DisableFlag Then
        Call starttimer
    Else
        Call Disable
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Disable()
    Dim dtZero As Date
    If m_dtNextTime <> dtZero Then
        ' Stop timer if it is running
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.OnTime m_dtNextTime, "TestActive", , False
        On Error GoTo 0
        m_dtNextTime = dtZero
    End If
    m_dtInterval = dtZero
End Sub

Sub start()
    'Start the timer
    DisableFlag = False
    ExcelIsActive = True
    'Sets the interval to be three seconds
    Call Enable(#12:00:03 AM#)
End Sub

Public Sub RefreshQuery()

'I do my stuff here

'Stop the timer until the next time the user launches the browser
DisableFlag = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to add an event handler for Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink.  You can then use the code below.  This just checks to see if the webpage has focus.  the  ' DO EVENTS ' is where you would add your code and then exit the sub

```
'********************* References used
'* Microsoft Shell Controls An Automation : shell32.dll*
'* Microsoft HTML Objects Library: MSHTML.dll expand » *
'* Microsoft Internet Controls: IEFRAME.dll *

Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Dim ie As InternetExplorer 'IE window variable
Dim sUrl 'url of the webpage
Dim dt As Date 'timer

'set the url to look for
sUrl = Target.Address
'set initial timeout period *used instead of browser ready due to page redirection.
'you should also check the browser ready status
dt = DateAdd("s", 5, DateTime.Now)
    Do While dt > DateTime.Now
        DoEvents
    Loop

'reset the timeout period to allow time to view and select
dt = DateAdd("s", 30, DateTime.Now)
Dim shShell As New Shell ' windows shell variable
    'continue loop until we hit the timeout or the webpage no longer has focus
    Do While dt > DateTime.Now
        'Loop through all the IE windows
        For Each ie In shShell.Windows
            'check to see if the URL's match
            If InStr(ie.LocationURL, sUrl) Then

            Dim hDoc As HTMLDocument
            'get the webpage document
            Set hDoc = ie.document
                'check to see if it has focus
                If Not hDoc.hasFocus Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Activate
                    '''''''''''''
                    ' DO EVENTS '
                    '''''''''''''
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Set hDoc = Nothing
            End If
        Next ie
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: +1! I would add a line `DoEvents` before `Loop`. This way, Excel will take way less resources but still do the job!

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I definitely like the idea of using an event handler for Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink. Some questions: It looks like this requires the user to use Internet Explorer as their web browser, correct? My code has to be flexible to using different browsers. This also loops the code for 30 seconds while the user is on the webpage? I don't think I need that in my particular case - I only need it to happen once when they leave the webpage. But I can see how that would be useful. I will try to post what I currently have later today.

Comment: @Iggy25 You are correct that it requires Internet Explorer.  The reason for the loop is that if it doesnt it will exit the sub and then you are no longer polling for the windows status. Once that happens you will not be able to determine when the window loses focus.

Comment: I have posted my current solution below.