# Can you schedule periodic data imports in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA function that, when invoked via a button on a sheet, extracts a .csv file from a website and imports it into my workbook. The problem is the file is uploaded in different time intervals during the day, so I have to periodically check the website.

Is there a way in VBA that I can schedule when a function is invoked?

Comment: I think you need to use VB6 and try creating exe for the same job and schedule it on server/PC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211715/how-to-make-a-macro-which-executes-periodically-in-excel

Comment: Like one of the answers in the link above from @gipadm I would and have for many years use Task Scheduler and a VBScript to call your macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Application.OnTime()` method which will allow you to schedule a Macro for a specific time amongst other settings. However you're probably best using VB Script or similar.

It's also important to note that the workbook would need to be open the entire time if you are going to use VBA, whereas a VBS file will run silently and can be triggered to run at startup.

If you're proficient enough with VBA then you shouldn't have a problem writing VBS.