# How to run Macros automatically after 15 minutes

Tags: excel, vba

thank you so much everyone for the help, i have successfully automated my process. what i have done is

I have added a code in a module1 which copies files from source folder to multiple Destination folders via partial name trick.

In Module2 i have added another code which after copying files to multiple destination, moves the files to another folder where i gather all the files of daily basis.

In order to automate both codes i have added module3 and calling both 1 and 2 module via it.

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()

    Call moveFilesFromListPartial_A     'Macro1

    Call MoveFilesTEST   'Macro2
   
End Sub
```

However I would like to request if there is any option where i can run these modules automatically after every 15 minutes. otherwise i need to press the run button again and again. If i can automate and can run module3 (whose code is mentioned above) then i believe the whole process can be run after every 15 minutes

I have tested one time application method by inserting module4 and have experimented the below mentioned code but not successful

```vb
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "my_Procedure"
```

Can anyone help please, i will really be greatful

regards

Comment: *run these modules automatically after every 15 minutes* If you mean to execute the code every 15 minutes **all the time** I'm pretty sure VBA is not the right approach for this because it would mean to have Excel opened 24 hours. If you mean to execute the code, **wait** 15 minutes and execute it again only once, then check [Application.Wait method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.wait)

Comment: Although I agree with @Foxfire And Burns And Burns theoretically it is possible by adding `Application.OnTime ...`

Comment: I would suggest you convert the VBA code to a VBS script and use the regular Windows Scheduler

Comment: @FunThomas: IMO not really an improvement. Then you can also put the code into a workbook open event and run Excel with this from the Windows Scheduler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a macro which executes periodically in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211715/how-to-make-a-macro-which-executes-periodically-in-excel)

Comment: @Storax: A VBS Script can run even without having Office installed (eg on a server). Shouldn't be too hard to convert code to VBS and not taking more time as to find out how to open a (hidden) Excel instance from scheduler and call a Macro (you need some kind of scripting anyhow).

Comment: Then you assume that the OP's code do not use any Excel functionality at all. Anyway, scripting is needed, right. Then I would prefer Powershell

Comment: Friends! the Aim is that the code should keep running whether the system is turn on or whether it is turned off.  Is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue - your `TimeValue` indicates 15 seconds - not minutes. So, it should be `TimeValue("00:15:00")`.

Secondly, you have to perform first run of your sub with `Application.OnTime` code and then re-lanuch it from other module.

Copy this code to This_Workbook object:

```vb
Sub Workbook_Open()
  Call x 'this code will run every time you open the workbook
End Sub
```

Copy code below to any module:

```vb
Sub x()
  Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "y"
End Sub

Sub y()
  MsgBox "test" 'replace this code with anything you need
  Call x
End Sub
```

However, I think you should pay attention to a comment from @Foxfire And Burns And Burns and @FunThomas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Call moveFilesFromListPartial_A     'Macro1
    Call MoveFilesTEST   'Macro2
End Sub
```

every 15 minutes you just add `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"),"Button1_Click"`

So, your code would look like that

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Call moveFilesFromListPartial_A     'Macro1
    Call MoveFilesTEST   'Macro2
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"),"Button1_Click"
End Sub
```

`Application.OnTime` will run `Button1_Click` every 15min. As long as you do not close Excel, hit the End button in the VBE, do debugging or for whatever reason the timer is not called this will work. In other words you can't use this for a productive environment but maybe it is sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Dear Experts, thanks, let me work on this and i will get back with results

Comment: Bravo!!!!! Thank you so much everyone especially Storax, i am able to run the macros successfully. Love you All

Comment: Respected Experts. With your help i am able to perform my tasks automatically. I would like to ask if all these macros (file copying and then moving to specific folder) can also be possible in google Drive? as I read Google Sheets does not support VBA codes specifically. is there anyway or if i need to purchase Google Cloud server? The aim is whether the computer is on or off, the services should keep running. your suggestions will be highly appreciated